# How to link contextual filters from user account reference to node via views

Tags: views

So I have a content type called 'band' that has a selection field for users as members of bands (band_member) in band content type.
I want to create a view that displays only the users profiles that are members of the band. I am using the 'profiles' module to create these though I have the profile type linked to display with the user account.
I know it is done through contextual filters and relationships though I am not sure how. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this view will be on a band page, your contextual filter just needs to be the content NID.

Then, I guess you have to add the band_members field. You might get lucky and be able to render all of the profile in the field settings.

If you can't get enough info or customisation for that, you could instead add the relationship for Entity ReferencED by band_member. That should give you extra user fields to add.

**Additional question from comments.**

> Also if I wanted to show a block in the sidebar that shows all bands this user is listed in how would I do this. So how do I create the contextual filter or relationship with a user mentioned in the band_members reference in band?

For this, you would create a new view showing `content: Band` and the contextual filter would be

```
Content: Band Member (field_band_member)
Appears in: node:band.
```

For that contextual filter, you into its settings and select

```
When the filter value is NOT available > Provide Default Value
```

and then select either `Current User` if you want the block to the show the bands of the logged in user all the time, or `User ID from URL` if you want it to show the bands of the currently viewed user profile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I wanted to get this view to display in a block that shows for the band page? I see how you mean with getting the profile fields to show as part of the node though I would prefer to have them in a separate block.

Comment: If you set the contextual filter to NID, and create a block in your view's settings, it will work on the band page.

Comment: Thanks once again. So do you mean create a block in the header or footer in the views settings? Also if I wanted to show a block in the sidebar that shows all bands this user is listed in how would I do this. So how do I create the contextual filter or relationship with a user mentioned in the band_members reference in band?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In the view, it's created here: https://i.imgur.com/qmBr5jn.png Then it will show up in `/admin/structure/block` where you can add it to a region and configure it to only show on band pages.I'll answer the edited part in my main answer.

Comment: What I meant is did you mean link a block in the header or footer from the settings col or create a block for the view.

Comment: Thanks I have this working for the user now as a field reference menu to link to the users bands. Now I will play some more and see how I go. BTW Thanks for the help so far. :)